# How do I subscribe to a NATS subject in Python and keep receiving messages?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, nats.io

I tried out the example below (from [this](https://docs.nats.io/developing-with-nats/receiving/async) page):

```py
nc = NATS()

await nc.connect(servers=["nats://demo.nats.io:4222"])

future = asyncio.Future()

async def cb(msg):
  nonlocal future
  future.set_result(msg)

await nc.subscribe("updates", cb=cb)
await nc.publish("updates", b'All is Well')
await nc.flush()

# Wait for message to come in
msg = await asyncio.wait_for(future, 1)
```

But this only seems useful for receiving one message.  How would I subscribe and keep receiving messages?

I've also seen [the package example](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py#basic-usage), but it seems to just play both sides of the conversation, then quit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know much about python, but looks like you are just waiting for one message and program ends. You should look at the subscriber example [here](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py/blob/master/examples/nats-sub/__main__.py). As you can see, there is a loop to wait forever or for the SIGTERM signal.

Comment: Thanks!  As usual on SO, I feel dumb now that you've pointed out the example I should have found in the first place.  I was also misinterpreting the `loop.run_forever()` in some of the other examples as re-running `run()` and re-subscribing each time, but it's really more like adding an endless loop at the end of the main goroutine in Go to keep things running.  So I also learned more about Python async today.

Answer (score 6):

You can find a long running service example as well: https://github.com/nats-io/nats.py/blob/master/examples/service.py

```py
import asyncio
from nats.aio.client import Client as NATS

async def run(loop):
    nc = NATS()

    async def disconnected_cb():
        print("Got disconnected...")

    async def reconnected_cb():
        print("Got reconnected...")

    await nc.connect("127.0.0.1",
                     reconnected_cb=reconnected_cb,
                     disconnected_cb=disconnected_cb,
                     max_reconnect_attempts=-1,
                     loop=loop)

    async def help_request(msg):
        subject = msg.subject
        reply = msg.reply
        data = msg.data.decode()
        print("Received a message on '{subject} {reply}': {data}".format(
            subject=subject, reply=reply, data=data))
        await nc.publish(reply, b'I can help')

    # Use queue named 'workers' for distributing requests
    # among subscribers.
    await nc.subscribe("help", "workers", help_request)

    print("Listening for requests on 'help' subject...")
    for i in range(1, 1000000):
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        try:
            response = await nc.request("help", b'hi')
            print(response)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error:", e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(run(loop))
    loop.run_forever()
    loop.close()
```